# How to plot Arima model with original time series?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot my original data set

```
ggplot(piz, aes(Date, Price.Dollars.per.Thousand.Cubic.Feet)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Later I have extracted one column and performed ARIMA modeling.

```
fit1
Series: a1 
ARIMA(4,1,1) 
plot(forecast(fit,h=48))
```

My image
[image]

If I go for autoplot solution

```
> a1=ts(a1)
> autoplot(a1) + forecast::autolayer(fit1)
Error in UseMethod("autolayer") : 
  no applicable method for 'autolayer' applied to an object of class "c('ARIMA', 'Arima')".
```

I am adding sample dataset

```
Date     Price Dollars per Thousand Cubic Feet
Jan-2002    3.1
Feb-2002    2.86
Mar-2002    3.37
Apr-2002    3.8
May-2002    3.78
Jun-2002    3.61
```

How to plot them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
  db<-data.frame(x=c(1:1000)+round(runif(1000,min = 5, max=100),0),
  date=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "day", length.out = 1000))

  fit<-auto.arima(y = db$x)

  plot(fit$x~as.Date(db$date),col="red",type="l",xaxt = "n",)
  lines(fitted(fit)~as.Date(db$date),col="blue")
  axis(1, db$date, format(db$date, "%b %d"), cex.axis = .7)
```

[image]

With a sample of your data I could be more specific.

Comment: Take a look at my inserted image,it has Date on x-axis.

Comment: Add a sample of your dataset and I will be more specific on your situation. Apart of this, is a plot with fitted data over real data what you want?

Comment: Answer modified with date.

Comment: I have added sample data set.